Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `fr.mind.mind.models.item.ItemCosmetic`
i've problem but idk what is it..
Someone can help me ?
How to patch it ?
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaConfiguration.class]: Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `fr.mind.mind.models.item.ItemCosmetic
@Entity
@Table
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ItemCosmetic {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private int id;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private Integer series;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String phoneNumber;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "buyerId", nullable = true)
    @JsonProperty("buyerId")
    @Getter(AccessLevel.NONE)
    private Player buyer;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "itemId", nullable = true)
    private Item item;
    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String renamed;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private int quantity = 1;
    @Column(nullable = false)
    private boolean isDrop = false;
    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.DETACH)
    @JoinColumn(name = "inventoryId", nullable = true, unique = false)
    private Inventory inventory;

    public int getBuyerId() {
        return buyer.getId();
    }

    public ItemCosmetic(
            Player buyer,
            Item item,
            Inventory inventory) {
        this.buyer = buyer;
        this.item = item;
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }

    public ItemCosmetic(
            Player buyer,
            Item item,
            int quantity,
            Inventory inventory) {
        this.buyer = buyer;
        this.item = item;
        this.quantity = quantity;
        this.inventory = inventory;
    }
}

Could not determine recommended JdbcType for `fr.mind.mind.models.item.ItemCosmetic

Hibernate may not be able to identify the JDBC type if the mapping is incorrect. Ensure the relationships are correctly defined.
